# JFrame does not refresh after deleting an image

Tags: java, image, jframe, bufferedimage

I'm working for the first time with images in a JFrame, and I have some problems. I succeeded in putting an image on my JFrame, and now i want after 2 seconds to remove my image from the JFrame. But after 2 seconds, the image does not disappear, unless I resize the frame or i minimize and after that maximize the frame. Help me if you can. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
        File f = new File("2.jpg");
```

System.out.println("Picture " + f.getAbsolutePath());
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
   MyBufferedImage img = new MyBufferedImage(image);
   img.resize(400, 300);
   img.setSize(400, 300);
   img.setLocation(50, 50);
   getContentPane().add(img);

this.setSize(600, 400);
   this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   this.setVisible(true);

Thread.sleep(2000);
   System.out.println("2 seconds over");

getContentPane().remove(img);

Here is the MyBufferedImage class:

```
public class MyBufferedImage extends JComponent{
 private BufferedImage image;

private int nPaint;
private int avgTime;

private long previousSecondsTime;

public MyBufferedImage(BufferedImage b) {
    super();

    this.image = b;

    this.nPaint = 0;
    this.avgTime = 0;

    this.previousSecondsTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2D.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    long currentTimeA = System.currentTimeMillis();


    //g2D.drawImage(this.image, 320, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 640, 480, null);
    g2D.drawImage(image, 0,0, null);
    long currentTimeB = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.avgTime += currentTimeB - currentTimeA;
    this.nPaint++;

    if (currentTimeB - this.previousSecondsTime > 1000) {
        System.out.format("Drawn FPS: %d\n", nPaint++);
        System.out.format("Average time of drawings in the last sec.: %.1f ms\n", (double) this.avgTime / this.nPaint++);
        this.previousSecondsTime = currentTimeB;
        this.avgTime = 0;
        this.nPaint = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call `this.repaint()` after removing the image and all will be well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling

<s>getContentPane().revalidate() ;</s>

after the call to remove?

Comment: There is no revalidate method, try using getContentPane().validate();

Or possibly (on the JFrame) do this.validateTree();

Comment: Doh!  Also, they want to watch out for adding and removing things off of the EDT

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to invalidate the frame component forcing a redraw.

Probably your best bet is to look at the update/repaint methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that you are removing your image from your component in the Event Dispatch Thread.  Give this a try:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
              getContentPane().remove(img);
         }
 }
```

Your `img` will either need to be a global or declared `final` in local scope for this to work.   Take a look at [concepts on Swing Threads](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) if you are not already familiar.

Note: The `remove` call on `Container` will call `invalidate()` if the content pane is considered valid.

Answer (score 0):

Give
`SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);` a Shot

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works. It works with SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this), this.repaint or this.update(getGraphics()). Have a nice day!